# Is there a way to direct the compiler to one overload when there is an ambiguous overload?

Tags: c++, overloading

```
#include <cstddef>

template<class T> T func(int*){ return T(0); };
int* someptr;
template<class T> T func(size_t v) { return func<T>(someptr + v); } 

int main()
{
    func<float>(nullptr);//int*
    func<float>(0);//error: 0 could be uint8_t* or size_t. 
    func<float>(NULL);//error: NULL could be uint8_t* or size_t. 
}
```

In the above code, is there a way for me to make it so that func(0); calls size_t overload and NULL calls the int* overload? I am aware that I can change the function names and I will do that if what Im trying to do is not possible. Thanks.

Comment: You can expliticly cast the value: `func<float>((size_t)0)` for example.

Comment: @CherryDT I was hoping there was a way for that to happen automatically.

Comment: With some compilers, `NULL` macro expands to `0`. At which point it's obviously impossible for `func<float>(0)` and `func<float>(NULL)` to behave differently.

Comment: @Apple_Bana There is: use a value of the type you want to call. The stupid part is how 0 is null in C++. The overload resolution isn't the stupid part.

Comment: Exactly. I was thinking of manually specializing but then got confused by how to handle the case of NULL expanding to 0.

Comment: The `NULL` problem is easily avoided by using `nullptr` instead.

Comment: I believe if you add a `template<class T> [[deprecated("pass size_t, not int")]] T func(int v) { return func((std::size_t)v);}` overload, then the problem goes away

Comment: Note that you can overload on [nullptr_t](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/nullptr_t).

Comment: Simply ban the use of `NULL` in your code. It has no place in 2023's C++.